# How to change the color of markers and add info window on @react-google-maps/api component?

Tags: google-maps, react-google-maps

I have a react code which shows some one or more locations on a @react-google-maps/api component. Here is a piece of my code which creates markers:

```
import { GoogleMap,  useLoadScript,  Marker, InfoWindow } from "@react-google-maps/api"

const Map = (props) => {

    Geocode.setApiKey(MY_API_KEY);

    const [locations,setLocations] = useState( [{
        lat: 41.4055,
        lng: 2.1915
    }])  
   

    useEffect(async () => {
      let addresses = Array.isArray(props.address) ? props.address :[ { 'address':props.address, 'selected':true}];
      let locations = [];
      let i;

      for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {

            await Geocode.fromAddress(addresses[i]).then(
              response => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                locations.push({lat,lng})
              },
              error => {
                console.error(error);
              }
            )
        }
      }
      setLocations(locations);
    }, [props.address])

    const generateMarker = () => (
      locations.map(location => {
        return (
          <Marker
            key = {location.lat}
            position = {location}
          />
        )
      })
    )

    return (
        <div>
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle = {mapContainerStyle}
            options= {options}
            zoom = {10}
            center = {center}
          >
            {generateMarker()}
          </GoogleMap>
        </div>
  )
}
```

how can I change the color of some markers to blue based on some special conditions? I want a location in my locations list to be a normal red marker and others in blue.

Also how can I add "info window" to each marker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if else` inside your `generateMarker` function and return different Marker objects. The if else depends on your condition. To create a blue marker, you can use a blue marker icon. To create an InfoWindow to each marker, use the `InfoWindow` object of the library inside the `Marker` object.

```
  const generateMarker = () =>
    locations.map(location => {
      if (location.lat === center.lat) {
        return (
          <Marker
            key={location.lat}
            position={location}
            icon={'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank.png'}
          >
            <InfoWindow>
              <div> Location of blue Marker
                {'(lat: ' + location.lat + ', lng: ' + location.lng + ')'}
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          </Marker>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Marker key={location.lat} position={location}>
            <InfoWindow>
              <div>
                {'(lat: ' + location.lat + ', lng: ' + location.lng + ')'}
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          </Marker>
        );
      }
    });
```

You can check this [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/marker-condition-sf9jxx?file=index.js) derived from your sample. put your API key in the `index.js` and in the Geocode instance to make the code work.